# Verification of mobile number phonegap app

Tags: ios, cordova

I m developing a phonegap app and I want to verify a user's mobile number when they are registering for the app.This verification is a one time process .

I want the typical verification code method where the user has the code texted to them. The user is presented with a text field where they enter their mobile number. They receive the verification code as sms . The verification code is entered in the app and verified. Once the verification is successful, the registration process is complete.

I researched about how to do this in phonegap for iOS but have not reached any useful tutorial . Hope you can point me in the right direction on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the free missed call based mobile number verification service from Cognalys for your app. They are offering 500 free international verifications everyday and provides example for all platforms too.

they released an open source project for phone-gap too. check their website or github for details.

Comment: they are actually really good - although I found their instructions for the sha code to be a bit weird - i had to use their java code to get my sha: https://cognalys.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/5000013544-how-to-get-access-token-app-id-and-sha. The SHA received using the java code was definitely not a SHA1 or a SHA256, do you know what type of SHA it is?

Answer (score 0):

You should find an SMS gateway with API access. Then when a users clicks on the registration button, you send him an SMS with a random code. Then the user have to submit that same code and you verify it on the server side.

Comment: Can we use the SMS gateway to send sms in any country? And does it cost for using it?